Login to "single tenant" app in Entra External ID tenat with "local account" via ciamlogin.com
I'm trying to create a public client desktop app which accesses Azure APIs.
To secure the access to those APIs, I have created an "Entra External ID" tenant ("for customers") where I registered my App and added a basic "email + password sign-up / sign-in" userflow. Then added
Then I created some "local" test users (users which have this entra external id as home directory) and gave them access to the resources that expose the APIs.
The app also has the required scopes registered and I gave an admin consent for every user in the tenant.
However, when I try the login flow with the following code (MSAL):
var clientId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
var tenantId = "yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy";
var tenantSubdomain = "tenantsubdomain";
var scopes = new string[] { "https://cognitiveservices.azure.com/.default" };

var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
        //.WithTenantId(tenantId) // with or without this line gets me the same result
        .WithAuthority($"https://{tenantSubdomain}.ciamlogin.com/{tenantId}")
        .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
        .Build();

var ar = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
// ...

The local users I created are rejected with the error message:

Error details: error invalid_request error_description:
AADSTS500207: The account type can't be used for the resource you're trying to access.
Trace ID: abc Correlation ID: def Timestamp: 2024-09-25 08:11:17Z

I can sign-up users from the login flow, but even those users are then rejected with the same error.
The "account type" to me normally means "personal" or "business", I'd expect "personal" accounts to be rejected (because of the "single tenant" config of the app), but not the accounts created in the same tenant.
This is such a common usecase that I think I'm missing something obvious, but I can't find it.
Change to scope
If I change the requested scope to https://graph.microsoft.com/.default, the login works, but I then can't use the token to access the services I need; as the request to the speech service in particular then fails with the error:

WebSocket upgrade failed: Authentication error (401). Please check subscription information and region name.
(yes, region name and subscription info are correct)

Similar questions:

Entra External Id with Microsoft Identity throwing AADSTS500208 unless user is Global Admin
The solution there seemed to be to use ciamlogin.com instead of login.microsoftonline.com, but this doesn't seem to apply to me.


Update for comments
Using login.microsoftonline.com the error is:

AADSTS500208: The domain is not a valid login domain for the account type

If I use an invited user on login.microsoftonline.com, the login works and I can access the services. But that wouldn't really work for my business.
Using https://{tenantSubdomain}.ciamlogin.com/{tenantId}/v2.0, https://{tenantId}.ciamlogin.com/{tenantId} or https://{tenantSubdomain}.ciamlogin.com the error is always again:

AADSTS500207: The account type can't be used for the resource you're trying to access

Here are some screenshots from the application registration:



What error did you get when you changed to login.microsoftonline.com

And also can you try like this .WithAuthority($"https://{tenantSubdomain}.ciamlogin.com/{tenantId}/v2.0")

@Rukmini - I get The domain is not a valid login domain for the account type and The domain is not a valid login domain for the account type again. I have edited the question.

Can you try this one https://tenantName.ciamlogin.com

The account type can't be used for the resource you're trying to access

Both, now. Same result

One last try:) https://TenantID.ciamlogin.com/TenantID/

$"https://{tenantId}.ciamlogin.com/{tenantId}" also gets me The account type can't be used for the resource you're trying to access

Can you confirm whether you have created b2c application by choosing "Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows)" or "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant – Multitenant)" option

yes. I have noticed however that if I remove the scope the login works, see details in updated question.

Unfortunately not.
The link you sent me above seems to relate to B2C tenants. I don't have a B2C tenant, but a Entra External ID tenant. Regarding CIAM logins not being able to access cognitive services in any case; that might be... But I'm unable to verify this, as I don't find any confirmation for this in the docs.

Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/external-id/customers/concept-supported-features-customers#application-registration

The following are the allowed permissions: Microsoft Graph offline_access, openid, and User.Read and your My APIs delegated permissions in external tenant

Posted the answer please check


Note that: According to this MsDoc, External tenant supports Microsoft Graph offline_access, openid,  and User.Read and your APIs delegated permissions not other API permissions.


And only the admin will be able to consent on behalf of the organization.

The error you are facing is because you are passing  https://cognitiveservices.azure.com/.default as scope to generate the access token in External ID tenant.

CIAM logins cannot access cognitive services.

Hence, to resolve the error pass scope as https://graph.microsoft.com/.default or your API scope while using External ID tenant.

Or make use of Workforce tenant/Microsoft Entra ID tenant to access cognitive services like below:

namespace TokenAcquisitionExample
{
    class Program
    {
        private static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var clientId = "MicrosoftEntraTenantAppID";
            var tenantId = "MicrosoftEntraTenantID";
            var scopes = new string[] { "https://cognitiveservices.azure.com/.default" };

            var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}")
                .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
                .Build();

            try
            {
                var ar = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"Token acquired:\n{ar.AccessToken}");
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"UI required exception: {ex.Message}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}



Thanks for your effort. Unfortunately the solutions you propose don't really solve my problem. 1: using https://graph.microsoft.com/.default doesn't give the user access to cognitive services. 2. "Don't use an external id tenant" doesn't really answer my question about how to use an external id tenant.. I gave you an upvote
